# Execution of some command every time a xerser starts: Turn on keyboard leds on startup by `xset led led on`

Tags: bash, xserver

My keyboard has background-leds, which can be turned on by pressing the Scroll-Lock-Key. The command I found to do so automatically in a shell is

```
xset led led on
```

Where can I execute this command on startup, BEFORE login? Is there any script that gets executed every time the xserver is started? Currently, I wrote the command in the .profile-file in my home directory, but this is not the best solution, as the entry is needed for all users, and during login the keyboard is not illuminated (so that the key labels can't be read).

My OS is Ubuntu Mate 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the /etc/rc.local file which will be executed after boot and run level changes. You can just throw the command right in there. You may also be able to use ~/.xinitrc or ~/.xsession depending on your specific setup (I'm not familiar with Ubuntu Mate).

Comment: I assume, the the files in the home directory like .xinitrc don't work, as they are executed at login?
I'll have a closer look at rc.local and rcX.d-scripts. this seems to be the right thing :)

Comment: ~/.xinitrc or ~/.xsession would usually be run when X starts or when the user logs in via login manager. This would likely be too late for your particular issue as it's usually going to be after login, but again, it may vary from setup to setup. Using the /etc/rc.local file is your best bet I would say.